# pinpoint from aws isn't recognizing my csv header to the addresses

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-pinpoint

I'm trying to import a csv file at the pinpoint, but it is always failing.

From the tutorials available from aws is supposed to work like this

```
Address,User.UserId
123123123,1
123123123,2
123123123,3
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your csv file it's missing required field ***"ChannelType"***, this explains why perhaps it's been failing.

A complete sample csv file should resemble the following :

```
ChannelType,Address,Location.Country,Demographic.Platform,Demographic.Make,User.UserId
SMS,2065550182,CA,Android,LG,example-user-id-1
APNS,1a2b3c4d5e6f7g8h9i0j1a2b3c4d5e6f,US,iOS,Apple,example-user-id-2
EMAIL,john.stiles@example.com,US,iOS,Apple,example-user-id-2
GCM,4d5e6f1a2b3c4d5e6f7g8h9i0j1a2b3c,CN,Android,Google,example-user-id-3
```

For a complete list of possible attributes, see [Supported Attributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/userguide/segments-importing.html#supported-attributes).